Dynamic URL using route is not working
My {custom_module}.routing.yml file code is as below:
custom_greeting.greeting:
  path: '/custom-greeting/{name}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_greeting\Controller\CustomGreetingController::greeting'
    _title: 'Custom Greeting'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    parameters:
      name:
        type: 'string'
        defaults: ''

I have created a controller page and as per the logic the url with user name will show message "Hello, @name! Welcome to our site." whereas the normal url will shows with message "Hello, welcome to our site!" but instead the normal url is redirecting to Page not found.
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_greeting\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CustomGreetingController extends ControllerBase {

  public function greeting(Request $request, $name = NULL) {
    // Check if $name is NULL or empty string
    if (!isset($name) || $name === '') {
      $message = $this->t('Hello, welcome to our site!');
    } else {
      $message = $this->t('Hello, @name! Welcome to our site.', ['@name' => $name]);
    }

    return [
      '#markup' => '<p>' . $message . '</p>',
    ];
  }

}

How to resolve this issue.

Per the docs for optional parameters, you need to provide the default value separately, under the existing defaults key:
custom_greeting.greeting:
  path: '/custom-greeting/{name}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_greeting\Controller\CustomGreetingController::greeting'
    _title: 'Custom Greeting'
    name: ''
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    parameters:
      name:
        type: 'string'


Thanks for the explanation that works.
